# c# how to call functions from function table?

Tags: c#, function, dynamic, dll, delegates

I have .NET `DLL` import library in my project, which functions I want to call taking its name from function `table (List<string>)`.

Assuming all they has same return type and parameters.

I have `functions_table[]` with something like "`Func1`", "`Func2`" ....

I randomly select from that table (really it is like List) and *call* it in my program.

As I can understand C# *delegate* is not for this solution.

I want to randomly choose function with name `Func1()` (for example) be called from managed C# code with their parameters.

How can be that achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MethodInfo handler = GetType.GetMethod("NameMethod");
handler.Invoke(context, new object[] {parameters}
```

does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Because you said that this functions must be called from managed code, I believe that functions DLL is native. So firstly, you need some native methods to load\free this library and call functions:

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string filename);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);
}
```

Then use this code to load DLL:

```
var libHandle = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(fileName);
if (libHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    // put error handling here if you need
}
```

And to free:

```
if (libHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(libHandle);
```

You will also need the delegate to make the call . For example,

```
delegate int FuncDelegate(int arg1, bool arg2);
```

And then to call the function from DLL:

```
var func1Address = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(libHandle, "Func1");
var func1 = (FuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(func1Address, typeof(FuncDelegate));
var result = func1(42, true);
```

And of course you can (and probably should) cache this functions:

```
private Dictionary<string, FuncDelegate> _functionsCache = new Dictionary<string,FuncDelegate>();
private int CallFunc(string funcName, int arg1, bool arg2)
{
    if (!_functionsCache.ContainsKey(funcName))
    {
        var funcAddress = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(libHandle, funcName);
        var func = (FuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcAddress, typeof(FuncDelegate));
        _functionsCache.Add(funcName, func);
    }

    return _functionsCache[funcName](arg1, arg2);
}
```

Comment: thx v1rusw0rm, but my functions is not from C/C++ DLL, it is managed code too, just from another dll.